# Javascript - Array emptying value at close of function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a function which calculates a total quote for an order, which then alerts the output to the user. I also want the total quote to be stored in an array so a separate function can be called which will display all the values in the array (displaying all the quotes since the page was loaded). From what i can work out the array loses the value pushed in by the function as the function ends, and I have played around with the scope of the array to no joy and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

```
<form>

<table id="kit" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">    

<th colspan="2" align="center"><h3>Purchase Shirts (Coming Soon)</h3></th>

<tr><td class="titles">Size</td>
    <td class="titles">Qty</td></tr>

<tr><td>Small (£10)</td>
<td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="5" name="small" /></td>

<tr><td>Medium (£12)</td>
<td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="5" name="medium" /></td>

<tr><td>Large (£15)</td>
<td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="5" name="large" /></td>

<tr><td>X-Large (£20)</td>
<td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="5" name="xlarge" /></td>

<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" onClick="return calculateShirts(this)" value="Get Quote" /></td>

</tr>   
</table>
</form>
```

JavaScript------------

```
var totalQuotes = [1,2]; //Initialise the global array with example values


function calculateShirts(form) //Function to calculate shirt 'quote'
{   
    //Assign Prices for Each Shirt Size
    var sml = 10;
    var med = 12;
    var lge = 15;
    var xl = 20;

    //Save the user inputs as variables
    var smlQu = form.small.value;
    var medQu = form.medium.value;
    var lgeQu = form.large.value;
    var xlQu = form.xlarge.value;

    //Multiply the Price by the User Input and save as variable
    var smlQuote = (sml * smlQu);
    var medQuote = (med * medQu);
    var lgeQuote = (lge * lgeQu);
    var xlQuote = (xl * xlQu);      

    //Add the calculated values together to get the total price
    var finalQuote = (smlQuote + medQuote + lgeQuote + xlQuote);

    //Create an array containing the quotes
    var arrayQuote = [smlQuote, medQuote, lgeQuote, xlQuote, finalQuote];

    //Variable containing the formatted output of quotes
    var output = "Your Kit Quote \n\n Small - £" + arrayQuote[0] + "\n" + "Medium - £" + quoteArray[1] + "\n" + "Large - £" + quoteArray[2] + "\n" + "X-Large - £" + quoteArray[3] + "\n\n" + "Total - £" + quoteArray[4];

    //Display the output variable in a popup box
    alert(output);


    totalQuotes.push(finalQuote);

    alert(totalQuotes); //This alert does show the calculated value
    return false;

}   



function printQuotes() //Function called on to display array values
{

    for (i in totalQuotes) {
        alert(totalQuotes[i]);

           //The calculated value is no longer in the array

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `for in` to loop over Arrays, use `for( idx; test; inc )`. `for in` is meant for iterating over the properties of Objects.

Comment: The variable arrayQuote seems to be referring to a global that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: The for in was just one of my fiddles i forgot to remove, sorry. I was originally just alerting the whole array at once.

Comment: I don't see what you mean jivings? It's all there to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me. There is some syntax error in there,

```
var output = "Your Kit Quote \n\n Small - £" + arrayQuote[0] + "\n" + "Medium - £" + quoteArray[1] + "\n" + "Large - £" + quoteArray[2] + "\n" + "X-Large - £" + quoteArray[3] + "\n\n" + "Total - £" + quoteArray[4];
```

You start by referencing arrayQuote then change to quoteArray, which doesn't exist. Not sure if this is just a typo when posting the question on here.

Given these values that I hardcoded:

```
var smlQu = 2;
var medQu = 1;
var lgeQu = 3;
var xlQu = 5; 

alert(totalQuotes); // returns 1,2,177

printQuotes(); // returns alerts  with  1 then 2 then 177
```

to stop the form refreshing add this line to the bottom of calculateShirts():

```
return false;
```

and change the form onsubmit from:

```
onsubmit="calculateShirts(this)" to onsubmit="return calculateShirts(this)"
```

if you still want to run the print method just call it before the return false.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be related to the inputs in the text fields? If it works when you run it without my html page for the inputs i'm assuming so.. The page seems to refresh or change in some way when i input values (putting them in the url)

Comment: Ah, yeah the onsubmit method will refresh the page when you submit the form. change onsubmit="calculateShirts(this)" to onsubmit="return calculateShirts(this)" and add 'return false;' to the end of your calculateShirts function

Comment: Ah right, can't believe I was only looking at the script.. Thank you!